# Return a specific object in a LINQ select query from two different objects in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list that could contain eg. the following objects

```
ObjectFirst {
id = 1;
mode = Constants.Active;
}

ObjectSecond {
id = 2;
mode = Constants.Passive;
}
```

How can I make a LINQ query that selects the object with "mode = Constants.Active" if that exists and if not it selects the object with the "mode = Constants.Passive"? Only one object should be returned. I would like to solve this with one LINQ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that could be done in one query but it could be done in multiple ways, You can try:

```
var obj = list.Any(r=> r.mode == Constants.Active) ? 
                            list.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.mode == Constants.Active)
                            list.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.mode == Constants.Passive);
```

Or:

```
var obj = list.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.mode == Constants.Active);
if(obj == null)
{
   obj = list.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.mode == Constants.Passive);
}
```

Comment: @Hanski, I am not sure if that can be done, plus even if it is possible to do that with a single query, would it really be readable ?

Comment: Thanks, that first is the one I'm looking for :)

Comment: @Hanski, first line is although appears to be a single statement, but it has multiple linq queries.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could order them by the `mode`, thus giving them a priority, and then return the first. Assuming that `Constants.Active` is lower than `Constants.Passive`.

```
var obj = list.OrderBy(r => r.mode).FirstOrDefault()
```

Optionally, you could add some extra checking:

```
var obj = list.Where(r => r.Id == someId).OrderBy(r => r.mode).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: That is a good hack, and would work for this situation, But might fail if the values are different , and wouldn't really convey the real intent of the code.

Comment: @Habib Could you further why you think it would fail if the values were different? Optionally a custom comparer could be used.

Comment: You could also order by bools:
`var obj = list.OrderByDescending(r => r.mode == Constants.Active).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @Richard, As I said, it would work perfectly for the current scenario, but mixing the logic to check for element existence and then getting it based on `OrderBy` doesn't seem right.